# Random multiplication generator not working. Can anyone help me? python

Tags: python

I'm making a random multiplication generator, but when I run it, it always comes out saying its wrong.

Even when I print the answer first and then directly copy it it comes out wrong.

Here's my code:

```
def generate_multiplication():
    a = randint(1, 12)
    b = randint(1, 12)
    answer = a * b
    print(answer)

    print(a, "x", b, "=")
    q = input()
    if q == answer:
        print("good")
    else:
        print("bad")
```

Pls help me!

Comment: `input` returns a string, and `answer` is an integer. To compare them, you must convert one to the other's type

Comment: I just realized this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `answer` is an integer and `input()` returns a string.